# How to put leading zeros in the Template class

Tags: python, python-templates

Need some help on the Template class syntax.  My old code is this:

```
filename = "Rule_{0:02d}{1}".format(1,".txt")
print(filename)
```

I want to convert it using Template but I don't know how to place one leading zero without using the format keyword again in the parameter:

```
#does not work
filename = Template("Rule_${pid:02d}${ext}").substitute(pid = 1, ext =  ".txt")
print(filename)
```

Just wanted to know how to use 0:02d in the Template.substitute if it is possible.  My access to the python website is blocked so I can't see the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Built-in `Template` class is for simple substitutions and it is not as powerful as format strings. Why do you want to use it in the first place?

Comment: Side note: you don't need a Python website to see the documentation, you can just type `help(Template)`.

Comment: @Selcuk thank you for your response.  I read that Template class is a more secure way to do string parameters.  I am currently hardening my code before production release.

Comment: In that case you can subclass `Template` and add your own features, but I highly doubt that it would worth it. As an alternative you can use a third party templating engine such as `jinja2`.